# How to public facebook messenger chatbot intergration dialogflow in order to everyone can receive response

Tags: facebook, dialogflow-es

How to make FB messenger chat bot intergration dialogflow public that every one can chat and receive response, because Messenger only response to User Who has role Admin or Tester.

Comment: why would you copy another thread? > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57844326/how-can-i-public-facebook-page-that-intergration-dialogflow-chatbot-in-order-to

Answer (score 1):

You have to submit your Facebook App for review, for this you need to :

1)To Activate the Facebook App. To do that,In your FB developer Console browse to Basic Settings of the page (from left sidebar) and provide Privacy Policy URL.
Another mandatory setting is selecting category. Clicking on “Choose a Category” will open up a popup where we can select appropriate category of our app.

Minimum required settings of App is in place. Click on Save Changes to save the settings and then click on Status toggle of app to activate it.

2) Now go to Bottom of your Dashboard you will see OPtions "Submit for Review" . CLick on that and fill necessary details and submit your app for review. Once reviewd by FB team your app will be live.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative you can use Rocketbots.io with its Dialogflow Integration :

https://docs.rocketbots.io/dialogflow-integration/dialogflow-v2-api-account-key